# Multiple Choice Columns-Checkboxes. Is there a different format?

Tags: office-365, lookup-column

I have a column which uses a lookup to another library. I need the user to be able to make multiple selections based on this lookup, however the problem I have is that this library contains hundreds of items. So when this is displayed as a multi check-box selection to the user it looks rather messy. Is there an alternative way to display choice/lookup columns to the user when multiple selections is turned on?

Using SP365.

Thanks
Sean

Comment: Can you share the screen shot of that messed up column.

Answer (score 2):

What you see is what you get. If you want a different UX, you can change how columns are displayed using [Client Side Rendering](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Client-side-rendering-JS-2ed3538a) (=JavaScript programming).

Check out the Chrome Browser plugin [Cisar](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cisar/nifbdojdggkboiifaklkamfpjcmgafpo?hl=en), this makes CSR programming a breeze (but you still need to know JavaScript)

Comment: Nice plugin for CSR. I just get to know today! Thanks. It will save my time in future. +1